# how to solve the java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

This is the code i have written for snake and ladder.Please help me out with the exceptions. the exception is on line 72 and 114 . I have highlighted the lines with comment which are leading to the exception.Thanks in Advance for help.

```
 package practical1;

 import java.io.Console;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class snakeandladder1 {

int totalpos=100;
int v=0;
int[] scores;
int score=0;
int l=0;

public int throwdice()
{
    int i=0;
    {
        while(i==0)
        {
            i=(int)Math.random()*100;
            i=i%13;
        }
        return i;
    }
}

public int ladder(int score)
{
    if(score==15)
        score=30;
    else if(score == 45)
        score=71;
    else if(score == 25)
        score=62;
    else if(score == 81)
        score=91;
    else if(score == 9)
        score=39;
    scores[l]=score;
    return score;
}

public int snake(int score)
{
    if(score == 29)
        score=11;
    else if(score == 81)
        score=48;
    else if(score == 92)
        score=71;
    else if(score == 30)
        score=6;
    else if(score == 58)
        score=19;
    scores[l]=score;
    return score;
}

void start()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the number of players:");
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=in.nextInt();
    in.close();
    l=n;
    System.out.println("Enter Players names in order:");
    ArrayList<String> name1=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        Console in1=System.console();
        String name2=in1.readLine(); //---- I am getting this null pointer exception here.
        name1.add(name2);
    }
    while(true)
    {
        while(l>0)
        {
            System.out.println("Click y to roll dice %d"+(l+1));
            Console in2=System.console();
            String yes=in2.readLine();
            if (yes == "y")
            {
                v=throwdice();
            }
            score = scores[l]+v; ((//--- the null pointer exception after changing all user input         to  scanner))
            if(score==totalpos)
            {
                System.out.println("User:"+name1.get(l)+" got "+v+".Winner!!!");
                break;
            }
            else if(score > totalpos)
            {
                scores[l]=scores[l];
            }
            int s1;
            s1=ladder(score);
            if(s1==score)
            {
                snake(score);
            }
            System.out.println("Current score of"+name1.get(l)+"is:"+scores[l]);
            l--;
        }
        if(l==0)
        {
            l=n;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    snakeandladder1 sal=new snakeandladder1();  ((//null pointer exception here as well after the changes))
    sal.start();   //------ i am getting this null pointer exception here 
}
```

}

Comment: Try `new Scanner(System.in)` to read the input from standard input stream. Read [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) - *Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine, if any, otherwise `null`.*

Comment: Can you share your full stacktrace?

Comment: Why do you use both `in` and `in1`? Two objects to get essentially the same thing (input from console)... use `in` and drop that `in1`

Comment: Search this site for "how to read a stack trace".

Comment: @Braj There's already a `Scanner` object in the code... what's funny is that it is used only once, closed, and then a `System.console()` is used to do the same thing

Comment: Why the extra pair of braces in `throwdice()`? Also, please use naming convention.

Comment: @Barranka As per Documentation of `System.console()` it returns `null` if not found. I just looked at the exception line as mentioned by OP and that is first point that came in my mind.

Comment: Just use the scanner you already have but don't close it.

Comment: Read [The Java Tutorials: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=in.nextInt();
in.close();
```

Please not that in the above code `close()` method will close not only the `Scanner` object itself but also its underlining stream (i.e. keyboard input). This happens to `System.in` and all other sources that implement `Readable`.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> When a *Scanner* is closed, it will close its input source if the source
>   implements the *Closeable* interface.

My suggestions:

- remove `in.close();`
- use `name2 = in.readLine();`

Comment: Hi...Thanks for the help.I got these cleared and understood how the sacanner object works                                                   this is the stack trace :                                             Enter the number of players:
2
Enter Players names in order:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at practical1.snakeandladder1.start(snakeandladder1.java:72)
 at practical1.snakeandladder1.main(snakeandladder1.java:114)

Comment: Hi ...now i another problem... The same problem is occuring with two other lines.. with line 83 and 115..   here is the stack trace.:Enter the number of players:
2
Enter Players names in order:
kishan
raghav
Click y to roll dice %d3
y
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at practical1.snakeandladder1.start(snakeandladder1.java:85)
 at practical1.snakeandladder1.main(snakeandladder1.java:113)

Comment: what i dont understand is how to clear this exception.The exception is for null pionter variables or objects but i havent assigned any variable or object null.please help....

Comment: Have you implemented my suggestion? If so, please post the updated code and any errors/exceptions you're still getting after the update. (All this information needs to be in your post, not in comments).